# How can I create a directory if one doesn't exist using Perl?

Tags: perl, directory

Currently, my Perl output is hard-coded to dump into the following Unix directory:

```
my $stat_dir = "/home/courses/" . **NEED DIR VAR HERE**;
```

The filename is built as such:

```
$stat_file = $stat_dir . "/" . $sess.substr($yr, 2, 2) . "_COURSES.csv";
```

I need a similar approach to building Unix directories, but I need to check if they exist first before creating them.

How can I do auto-numbering (revisions) of the $stat_file so that when these files get pumped into the same directory, they do not overwrite or append to existing files in the directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `-d` operator and [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);
eval { make_path($dir) };
if ($@) {
  print "Couldn't create $dir: $@";
}
```

`make_path` has an advantage over `mkdir` in that it can create trees of arbitrary depth.

And use `-e` to check file exists

```
my $fileSuffix = 0;
while (-e $filename) {
    $filename = $filePrefix . ++$fileSuffix . $fileExtension;
}
```

Comment: Checking $@ is unreliable.  Use eval{mkpath($dir); 1} or do { warn "badness\n" }.  See http://search.cpan.org/dist/Acme-ExceptionEater/lib/Acme/ExceptionEater.pm for an example of why checking $@ is bad.

Comment: As of v2.09(2013-01) it appears that it is now make_path

Answer (score 19):

Erm... `mkdir $stat_dir unless -d $stat_dir`?

It really doesn't seem like a good idea to embed 'extra' questions like that.

Comment: I kind of agree, but figured they are a good package deal to know when trying to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 7):

Remember the directory's `-d` existence doesn't mean `-w` writable. But assuming you're in a personal area the `mkdir($dir) unless(-d $dir)` would work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has a built-in function `mkdir`

Take a look at perldoc perlfunc or the mkdir program from [Perl Power Tools](http://www.metacpan.org/module/PerlPowerTools).

I believe it is safe to create a directory that already exists, take a look at the docs.